# Validation for decimal field to restrict blank values and string values in visual force page

Tags: visualforce, controller, validation, decimal

I have a visual force page in which I have a field to accept decimal values. I can restrict the user from entering `0.0` and `null` values, but I cant do the same for `''` (Empty String). Is there any method that would come in handy to solve my problem?

Comment: That can be done on server and client side too. Are you using VF or HTML tags for the field? And how are you preventing the user from entering 0.0 and null currently? Can you please post some code?

Comment: im doing the validation in the controller . like `if(amount == 0.00 || amount == null){
                    ErrorMsg =  'AMOUNT REQUIRED' +'<br/>';
                }`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use Javascript :

```
<input type="text" onkeyup="this.value = this.value.replace(/[^\d.]/g, '');" />
```